# rvest - Scrape list and store items separately

Tags: r, rvest

I  am trying to scrape information from a webpage:

```
rm(list = ls())

library(rvest)
library(XML)
library(dplyr)

utils::setInternet2(TRUE)
options(download.file.method = "internal")

url <-"http://www.home24.at/smood/premium-komfortmatratze-smood-180-x-200cm"

pgsession <- html_session(url)               ## create session
pgform    <- html_form(pgsession)[[1]]       ## pull form from session

pflege <- pgsession %>% 
               jump_to(url) %>% 
               read_html() %>% html_nodes(xpath="//*[@id='product-details']/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[5]/ul") %>% 
               html_text()
```

I get the results like the following back:

```
"Doppeltuchbezug bis 95Â°C waschbarWebstoffbezug kann in die Reinigung gegeben werden"
```

However, I would like to get the results like that back, so separated for each list item:

```
"Doppeltuchbezug bis 95Â°C waschbar", "Webstoffbezug kann in die Reinigung gegeben werden"
```

Any suggestions how to separate the strings and scrape each list item individually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use an XPath or CSS selector that will select both elements you want. To find an appropriate selector, inspect the HTML in a web browser; automatically generated ones are rarely optimal.

```
# pull page once and store in case you want to parse multiple elements
page <- pgsession %>% jump_to(url) %>% read_html()

page %>% html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@data-reactid="350"]/li') %>% html_text()

## [1] "Doppeltuchbezug bis 95°C waschbar"                 
## [2] "Webstoffbezug kann in die Reinigung gegeben werden"
```